# how it is executing for $a++ + $a++ + $a vs $a + $a++ + $a++

Tags: php

I've seen a question on SO like this and confused :( , as I know `$a++` will increment value that will  available when I'll print `$a`, itll print 2 . but if I print `$a++` it is 1 not 2

```
<?php
 $a=1;
 echo $a + $a++ + $a++; // it returns 5
?>
```

but

```
<?php
 $a=1;
 echo $a++ + $a++ + $a ;// it returns 6
?>
```

I want to know why the later in prints 6 instead if 5? not sure about associativity or precedency for now. can anyone explain?

Comment: any specific reason for voting it down?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php  Might be helpful. Look around Example #2.

Comment: @ay ber thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `++` occurs after the variable, it's a "post-increment" operator, meaning the initial value is returned before incrementing. When it occurs before the variable, it's a "pre-increment" operator, which increments before returning the newly-incremented value.

Additionally, when evaluating `left + right++`, you need to evaluate `right++` first because post-increment takes precedence (you need to return the value before you can evaluate the addition).

Thus `$a + $a++ + $a++` will evaluate as `($a + (1++)) + $a++ -> (2) + 1 + ($a++) -> 2 + 1 + (2++) -> 5`, and `$a++ + $a++ + $a` will evaluate as `(1++) + $a++ + $a -> 1 + (2++) + $a -> 1 + 2 + (3) -> 6`.

Comment: thats exactly i wanted. clear and concise.also thumbs up but itll not shown coz my reputation is  below 15 so up vote my question once :)

Comment: Note: This is not true of all programming languages! In fact, test against JavaScript and you will see that the result is very different, with the first expression resulting in `4` instead of `5`. This is very possibly a PHP-specific quirk of operator precedence. Be sure to research operator precedence of any language you're using before assuming that the behavior will be the same :)

Comment: I'm not sure the second paragraph is true. The manual states it returns first, increments later. Might as well be incrementing the final value.

Comment: @msg It is returning first before incrementing. Note that I'm stating that the right term is evaluated first, then the left, because of the presence of the post-increment operator. This would mean that `x + x++` would evaluate as `x + (1++) -> x + 1 -> 2 + 1 -> 3`. In most languages you would expect a strict left-to-right evaluation, but PHP is really weird about things like this.

Comment: I guess I missinterpreted the "need to evaluate `right++`" part as evaluating the whole right *expression*, increment included, instead of the right *operand*. The third paragraph breaks it down as I expected.

Answer (score 2):

The explanation might be a bit confusing:
`$a++` construct returns the variable **current** value and **then** increments.

So what it's happening in the first case is that you are echoing: 
1 + 1 + 2 + 1 = 5. The last `1` is the result of the pending `++` operation.

In the second case you have 1 + 2 + 3 = 6. `2` is the value after the increment that in that iteration becomes 3.

There is no precedence here since are all additions.

The counter example is the preincrement:

```
$a = 1;
echo ++$a + $a;
```

It *should* print `4`. The first operation increments and then returns so `2` and the second is still `2`.

How the operator behaves is explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya you are [mistaken](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

Comment: i got it but i need ine more clarification. for later case post increme t haz more priority over addition thats why it is exechting from left to right ?

Comment: @print_r When asking about clarification, please be more detailed as to what's unclear. It's not about precedence here, addition is simply executed left to right. Your question is already about a semantic edge case. There's little use of pre/post-increment operators in real world code anyway.

Comment: yea sir i understood. actually i m not clear why for later case it is considering from left to right not right to left as it is doing for 1st case. operator precedency is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

1-read code left to right
2-note: what is $a++  , it's a "post-increment" operator, meaning the initial value is returned (return to sum machine) before incrementing.

```
echo $a++ + $a++ + $a;
```

same as:
     echo ($a++ + $a++) + $a;
          (p1)    (p2)   (p3)
            1    +  2     + 3  = 6

first a = 1

in (p1) a is 1:

1 enter in **sum machine** then a increase

current value of a is 2

in (p2) a is 2 :

2 enter in **sum machine** then a increase

current value of a is 3

in (p3) a is 3 :

3 enter in **sum machine** then no change

current value of a is 3

output of sum machine is 6